# Angular2 - How module is different from component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In the below code from `../src/app/app.module.ts`,

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
```

---

Component consists:

- view(`../src/app/app.component.html`)
- logic(`../src/app/app.component.ts`)
- style(`../src/app/app.component.css`)

Angular application is a tree of components. Good components have *high cohesion*, i.e. each component contains only elements with related functionality. They are also well encapsulated and *loosely coupled*.

---

How modules are different from components?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between an Angular component and module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073941/whats-the-difference-between-an-angular-component-and-module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A module is something that *has* components. It wraps them up so you can import and manage them.

Notice when you make a component you can put anything that's decorated as `@Injectable` in your constructor:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And magically you will have a `myService` to use. This is dependency injection, which is built into Angular - but it's managed on a `Module` level. In your module you import what other modules you want to be able to use:

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule
],
```

define what your module includes:

```
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  HeroesComponent,
  MyService
],
```

export any components (so other modules can import them)

```
exports: [
  HeroesComponent
],
```

They help organize an application into blocks of functionality. Components are things that tell angular how to render something. Modules compose Components, Pipes, Services etc into 'blocks' that can be compiled by angular or imported and used by others.

## Edit to address comment

Taking your specific question about [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http). The `HttpClient` is the *service* you are using to perform the actions. The `HttpClientModule` is the *module* you import into your module, so you can use the *service* it contains.

You import the module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // Include it under 'imports' in your application module
    // after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
})
```

And *use* the service:

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
 
  // Inject HttpClient into your component or service.
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ...
}
```

The `HttpClientModule` contains within it all you need for the `HttpClient` to work, and packages it up so you can use it in your own projects.

This particular module only wraps up that one service, but the module could contain a bunch of related services, components, pipes or directives. For example, the `RouterModule` allows you to use the `RouterOutlet` and `RouterLink` directives.

Comment: Does Angular2 encourage single page app, with root component?

Comment: Yes. Or libraries of functionality that can be imported - but the project that imports it will very likely be an SPA with a root component.

Comment: For example: How would you differentiate `HttpClientModule`(@angular/common/http) from `HttpClient`(@angular/http)? Why first one is called the module? We need both for http facility. Am trying to understand the purpose of module with this example

Comment: I've added some explination in an edit to the answer.

Comment: When we already import httpclientmodule in app.module.ts, why do we need to import httpclient service again? Can’t the module import provide it’s service?

Comment: You don't import the httpclient service like you import an Angular module, you *inject* it as a dependency into the constructor. That provides your component or service an instance to actually use. Are you refering to the typescript `import { HttpClient } from...`? That's not Angular modules, but Typescript modules - and is much more generic and nothing to do with Angular (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html). Typescript modules are what you do with the `export myThing...` in all your typescript files, and how they use each other.

Comment: Okay, tha's understandably confusing. Like I said, the Typescript Modules are a separate thing to Angular Modules, it's just how all typescript is composed. Angular Modules are specific classes with the `@NgModule()` decorator (they are also exported as a typescript module, like almost all the typescript you'll use).

Comment: As you said, any component that is injectable thru constructor. What is `@Input() x`, `@Output() y`?

Comment: `Inputs` are things that can be set in the template by a parent component. Say you have a component with the selector "my-custom-input" and had an `@Input() text` you could set the child component in the root component's template: `<my-custom-input text="hi!"><\..` Output is similar, but works like events, so `<my-custom-input (someOutput)="doFunc()">..` the documentation provides good examples of all these in the heroes tutorial.

Comment: In your example of `RouterModule`, i do not see importing that module in `@NgModule(imports: [..])` of `app.modules.ts` but used in `app.routes.ts`  directly as `RouterModule.forRoot()`. how do I understand this?

Comment: I'd have to see more of your code than those two snippets, and this is a whole new question, I suggest you post it as a new question.

Answer (score 4):

A **component** is just a class with the `@Component()` annotation. Note that .html and .css files *might* be referenced by the component, certainly not mandatory. The component template might very well be 'inlined' directly in the component configuration, or there simply might not be any html template at all for a given component.

A **module** is a structural element of an Angular application (and maybe other classes and interfaces). It is also "just a class" with the `@NgModule()` annotation.

It acts as a logical 'container' for your components, directives, services, pipes, etc... to help you structure your overall source code better.

You can have a look at this existing question : [What's the difference between an Angular component and module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073941/whats-the-difference-between-an-angular-component-and-module)

Answer (score 0):

**Module** in angular is set of Components, Services, Filters, or some another smaller modules too, or we can say where you import all these in order to use later in the app for future use. in a single app there can be one or more than one module may exist.

Whereas, A **component** controls a patch of screen called a view.
You define a component's application logic—what it does to support the view—inside a class. The class interacts with the view through an API of properties and methods.

Refer this guide for more details:

https://angular.io/guide/architecture